# Architecturally correct way to persist "balance" entity

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Say we have `balance` entity in our appliation which is represented by exactly one row in the database. It's updated with diferent actions like `deposit`, `withdrawal`, etc.

Now I have a stress-test which contineously creates a `deposits`s and delete it right after.
Idealy I want to have 0-balance at the end of test - so every created `deposits` increses the `balance`, say +1cu, and deleting it decreses it with -1cu accordingly

But what happens is:

- If transaction have isolation level <= `READ_COMMITED` - no errors occure, but the resulting balance != 0, as these transactions override changes made by one another. Which is very bad - we either lose money or get them from the air
- If transaction have isolation level >= `REPEATABLE_READ` - we still have balance != 0 and a bunch of errors in console, as some transactions didn't worked out. Unless I specify `@Retryable`, in which case balance == 0, but still errors in console, which may be OK. `@Retryable` also has `maxAttempts` parameter which is defaults to 3. It feels like i can't be sure this "3" is always gonna be enough.

It doesn't feel right to have balance as one table row. But always recalculating it as a sum of every possible operations is also odd.

I've tried to add additional table for collecting all of upcoming changes to balance before applying them, but still faced that one-row-bottleneck

**TLDR**

How do I set up balance persistence using Spring and PostgreSQL? Is there any Best Practices or patterns for that case?

Comment: Best practice is to *not* store this redundant sum in the database, since it will severely impact your data modification performance, even if you do it right.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thank you for reply! Should I recalculate this sum every time it's required? Won't it become expensive one day?

Comment: Yes, that will be expensive. So if you query that sum all the time and have comparatively few data modifications, storing that sum might actually be a good idea. If you have many concurrent data modifications, the performance cost of maintaining the sum will be forbidding.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by 'deleting' a deposit, or isolation level  <= READ_COMMITED, specifically with the <?  You shouldn't be updating a calculated field with an absolute value without being sure you have the correct state at the time of writing - try using optimistic locking to detect changes made since your thread last read in the balance, and force re-reading it if it has changed out from under the transaction, or try a pessimistic approach to lock the value when you are working on it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to recalculate the sum all the time and use timestamp based partitioning with a summarization table to improve performance.

The idea is that you have an `actions` table (containing deposit and withdrawal) which is partitioned by timestamp, and the "current" partition will only have a limited set of data i.e. for the last N months. Then, at the start of a new month, you can add a new partition and hence move old data to that partition. As part of the transaction that creates the partition, you also create a row in the summarization table, which consists of e.g. `(year, month, balanceDelta)`.

Finally, you query this like `select sum(a.balance) + (select sum(st.balanceDelta) from summarization_table st) balance from actions a`.

To improve performance further in the long run, you could also pre-aggregate multiple months.

Overall, I think that an approach like TimescaleDB (PostgreSQL extension) uses with its continuous aggregates is the most scalable and easiest, but not sure if you can install that extension.